# Retrieve deleted rows on deletion

Tags: go, delete-row, go-gorm

Is there a way to retrieve the rows deleted when calling Delete()?

I'd like to avoid using 'SELECT ... FOR UPDATE' to first get the list of rows I'm deleting.

```go
type MyModel struct {
  gorm.Model
  ....
}

res := db.Where("updated_at < ?", expirationDate).
    Set("gorm:save_associations", false).
    Delete(&MyModel{})
```

I noticed there is a res.Value attribute but it seems to be the empty struct I pass as argument of Delete().

Comment: gorm does not do it due to spotty db support for this. You'll need to execute a raw sql statement such as `DELETE .... RETURNING ....` on postgres. I think mysql doesn't have that though, but you didn't specify which database it's for.

Comment: In newer versions of gorm, you can add a [Returning clause](https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Returning-Data-From-Deleted-Rows) `.Clauses(clause.Returning{})` if the db supports the `RETURNING` keyword (eg Oracle, Postgres). For MySQL, you'll have to "hack" it by making a temporary table or doing a find followed by delete to get the deleted records.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be this way instead. `db.Where` does not return the struct. It modifies the pointer passed as parameter.

```
var res MyModel{}

db.Where("updated_at < ?", expirationDate).
    Delete(&res)
```

Comment: This still wouldn't populate `res` with the data that was deleted based on my testing today. He'd need to use a [returning clause](https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Returning-Data-From-Deleted-Rows) and pass in an array of models to get it populated by gorm with the deleted data automatically.